# Custom IValueRetriever for existing base type

Tags: c#, specflow

I'm testing date dependent logic, which requires me to generate datasets with dates equal to the date of test run, as well as for static dates like 2020-03-09. For example:

```
| Date             | Id    | Value        |
| {CURRENT_DATE-1} | 11    | 151000000.00 |
| {CURRENT_DATE-1} | 27    | 296000000.00 |
| {CURRENT_DATE-1} | 29    | 297000000.00 |
| {CURRENT_DATE-1} | 35    | 296000000.00 |
| {CURRENT_DATE-1} | 42    | 326000000.00 |
| {CURRENT_DATE-1} | 10061 |  61000000.00 |
```

This task looked pretty similar to `NullValueRetriever` discussed [here](https://specflow.org/documentation/SpecFlow-Assist-Helpers/), so I decided to write my own `IValueRetriever` for `DateTime`. Because adding this new retriever might override the existing one, I decided to extend existing `DateTimeValueRetriever` and augment its functionality.

```
public class CurrentDateRetriever : DateTimeValueRetriever, IValueRetriever
{
    private const string Current_Date_RegEx = @"\{CURRENT_DATE(?:([-\+])(\d+)){0,1}\}";

    private readonly Regex _CurrentDayRegex = new Regex(Current_Date_RegEx);

    public bool CanRetrieve(KeyValuePair<string, string> keyValuePair, Type targetType, Type propertyType)
    {
        var value = keyValuePair.Value;

        var match = _CurrentDayRegex.Match(value);

        return (propertyType == typeof(DateTime) && match.Success);// ||
            // Cannot check the base class implementation,
            // as it doesn't have 'CanRetrieve' even though 'IValueRetriever'
            // interface is in the inheritance chain
            // base.CanRetrieve(keyValuePair, targetType, propertyType);
    }

    public object Retrieve(KeyValuePair<string, string> keyValuePair, Type targetType, Type propertyType)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

For some reason the neither `DateTimeValueRetriever`, nor its ancestors `NonNullableValueRetriever<T>` do not define `CanRetrieve`, even though they state to implement `IValueRetriever` interface. I'm trying to understand why I cannot see the base class method implementation, and how to write this retriever without loosing any existing `DateTime` conversion functionality.

P.S. I'm aware of `StepArgumentTransformation` with regex parameter ([ref](https://specflow.org/documentation/Step-Argument-Transformations/)), but I don't believe it will work table transformations.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using Specflow 3.1.97 and in it's case the following worked to convert strings like `{CURRENT_DATE+1}` to correct `DateTime` object.

```
public class CurrentDateRetriever : NonNullableValueRetriever<DateTime>, IValueRetriever
{
    private const string Current_Date_RegEx = @"\{CURRENT_DATE(?<days>[-\+]\d+){0,1}\}";

    private readonly Regex _CurrentDayRegex = new Regex(Current_Date_RegEx);

    public CurrentDateRetriever() { }

    public bool CanRetrieve(KeyValuePair<string, string> keyValuePair, Type targetType, Type propertyType)
    {
        var value = keyValuePair.Value;

        var match = _CurrentDayRegex.Match(value);

        return propertyType == typeof(DateTime) && match.Success;
    }

    public object Retrieve(KeyValuePair<string, string> keyValuePair, Type targetType, Type propertyType)
    {
        return GetValue(keyValuePair.Value);
    }

    public override DateTime GetValue(string value)
    {
        var match = _CurrentDayRegex.Match(value);

        if (!match.Success)
        {
            throw new ApplicationException("This retriever was wrongly selected");
        }

        var resultDate = DateTime.Now.Date;

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(match.Groups["days"].Value))
        {
            return resultDate;
        }

        int days = int.Parse(match.Groups["days"].Value);

        resultDate = resultDate.AddDays(days);

        return resultDate;
    }
}
```

I noticed that Specflow 3.1.97 will try every possible registered transformers for a value until it either finds the one that is applicable, or fails to convert. So, the new custom retriever for `DateTime` will not impact the builtin `DateTimeValueRetriever`.

Unfortunately, custom retriever is not automatically picked up (in Specflow 3.1.97) for transforming step arguments. That's why you need to define another `StepArgumentTransformation`, if you use custom "macro" as an argument.

```
[StepArgumentTransformation(@"\{CURRENT_DATE([-\+]\d+){0,1}\}")]
public DateTime ToCurrentDateTime(string days)
{
    var resultDate = DateTime.Now.Date;

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(days))
    {
        return resultDate;
    }

    resultDate = resultDate.AddDays(int.Parse(days));

    return resultDate;
}
```